# Xamarin: list view cell height at start

Tags: listview, xamarin

Using a listView, I am experimenting (only on iOS) that dynamic cells are showed bad a start. The cell are a mix of Image and text and at first execution, text an image are mixed. 
Then, after scroll they resized well.

My code is:

```
<ListView x:Name="MyListView"  HasUnevenRows="true" IsVisible="false">
                    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>

                             <ViewCell>
                                <StackLayout Spacing="6" Margin="16">

                                    <Image   Aspect="AspectFill">
                                        <Image.Source>
                                          <UriImageSource Uri="{Binding Imagen}"/>
                                        </Image.Source>
                                    </Image>   

                                    <Label  Style="{StaticResource Noticia}" Font="11" Text="{Binding Fecha, StringFormat='{0:dd/MM/yyyy}'}"/>
                                    <Label  Style="{StaticResource Titular}" Text="{Binding Titular}" />
                                 </StackLayout>
                            </ViewCell>


                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                </ListView>
```

how solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Looking at your code you are asking your image to fill a stacklayout of undefined height. Would say the solution here is to define height manually. Easy when your images are all like 100 height.

But if you want to have a dynamic image height then please let me welcome you to the world of a limited xamarin listview and propose several solutions.

1. Respond to image loaded event (you might have one for sure - `Success`, if you are using ffimageloading plugin) obtain the recieved image original width/height and calculate your needed heightrequest proportionally upon your current listview width.

   ```
               double ratio = item.ImageHeight / item.ImageWidth;
               item.ImageDynamicHeight = ratio * basewidth;  //basewidth can be YourListView.Width, remember to check if it's not -1
   ```
2. More fun to come: your server api must include image original height/width info in passed data, you will set heightrequest according to this info and then your image will perfectly land inside when downloaded. Using this solution for news feed lists, server passing me news images height along with news texts.
3. If you do not have many memory consuming rows you can let yourself use a custom control, consisting of a stacklayout with a bindable `Source` property, your cells becoming children of this stacklayout, what visually will behave more like it should and more smooth that a standard xamarin.forms listview. Using this solution for menu lists, short products lists and such.

Comment: Tx. How implement a image loaded event?

Comment: Use https://github.com/luberda-molinet/FFImageLoading available as nuget, image caching etc. Than you can set your CachedImage Success="ImageLoadedEvent" will be triggered when image is loaded